# Representable functors and symplectic co-tangent bundles

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, representable-functors

I've been banging my head against something that I feel should follow from abstract non-sense, and I hope someone here can set me straight.

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be the category of smooth manifolds, with morphisms given by smooth maps.  Suppose I have a functor

$F: \mathcal{M}\rightarrow Sets$

so that there exists a smooth manifold $M_{F}$ and a natural isomophism

$F(-)\simeq C^{\infty}(-, M_{F}).$

As with any smooth manifold, there exists a canonical symplectic structure $\omega$ on $T^{\star}M.$

**Question:**  Is there a notion of cotangent space/bundle/functor (sorry for the vagueness) to $F$ which recovers the canonical symplectic structure $\omega$ on $T^{\star}M?$

If it makes things any easier, you are free to assume that $F$ is a lax groupoid valued functor and is a representable stack (for your favorite Grothendieck topology on $\mathcal{Man}$), though I don't know if this makes much of a difference for this question.

I've heard of the cotangent complex to a stack, and this is likely the kind of thing I'm looking for, but wading through the technicalities is proving difficult.

Ideally, I'm interested if something like the following is true.  Let $(x, \alpha)\in T^{\star}M_{F}.$  Then look at $T_{(x, \alpha)}T^{\star}M_{F}.$  The symplectic form on $T^{\star}M_{F}$ induces a linear isomorphism

$T_{(x, \alpha)}T^{\star}M_{F}\simeq (T_{(x, \alpha)}T^{\star}M_{F})^{\star}\simeq Hom_{\mathbb{R}}(T_{(x, \alpha)}T^{\star}M_{F}, \mathbb{R}).$

Does this isomorphism arise in some natural way from some cotangent type object attached to the functor F?

It seems this question is already interesting for functors $F$ of the form

$F(U)=C^{\infty}(U,M)$

for some smooth manifold $M.$  But sadly, already here, I don't understand the obvious thing that I should do.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: I am a little skeptical about this because taking a cotangent bundle is not functorial.